# Something like input type date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

I need something like input `type='date'` when i'm clicking the input on mobile to appear the specific datepicker from phone.. Example for iphone [image: iphone]

But I want to display the date how I want.. Exactly what I need is to display the date like this: dd/mm/yy

Comment: How about [`datebox`](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: Users become familiar with the default UI of their device, it may be confusing or annoying if you mess with that.

Comment: @RobG yeah but I want just after selecting the date from the default UI of the device, to display selected date ..how I want....that is after the user select what date want

Comment: The issue with dd/mm/yyyy (and mm/dd/yyyy) is that for many dates it is ambiguous unless you also include a hint of the format. Better to use an unambiguous format like 19 December, 2016. Just a suggestion. ;-)

Comment: @RobG understand but now after select date on mobile in the input I have for example Dec 19, 2015 instead 19/12/2015. The client want to display the date like this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this HTML5 tag:

```
<input type="date" value="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
```

where you can set "value" as the default date.

You can also use min="YYYY-MM-DD" and max="YYYY-MM-DD" for maximum and minimum dates.

and as for the mask "DD/MM/YYYY", I recommend using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), where you can have tons of options to mask as you want.

Comment: Try looking at this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Bootstrap-datepicker it's ok for the mask but, not opening the default look on mobile:/